# How to convert List of values to Array in ASP .Net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to display list of student grade details like below

```
grade = ["FirstGrade", 5 "25 - 23" ],
        ["secondGrade", 3 "18- 20" ]
```

List contains data like

```
   [0] -   FirstGrade
           5 
           25 
           23 
   [1] -   secondGrade 
           3 
           18 
           20
```

Comment: Can you please share more details on list Like which type it is. and also share How you can store data into the list

Comment: Hi Tony,
i am reading the data from database and binding to List.
List is a class type, using like this  List<Grade> gr = new List<Grdae>();

Comment: Can you please share structure of Grade class?

Comment: public class Grade
    {
        public string gradeName { get; set; }

        public int grade       { get; set; }

        public string marks    { get; set; }

      }

Comment: Can you please share data that inserted into list I mean code?

Comment: private List<Grade> GetGrade(string gradeName, int Grade, string marks)
        {

            List<Grade> garde= new List<Grade>() { new Grade()
            {
                gradeName = gradeName,  grade= grade, marks = marks
            }};

            return garde;
        }

Comment: Please update the Question with your updated/added code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code, I think its same as you want

```
        List<Grade> grades = new List<Grade>();

        grades.Add(new Grade { gradeName = "FirstGrade", grade = 5, marks = "25 23" });
        grades.Add(new Grade { gradeName = "FirstGrade", grade = 3, marks = "18 20" });

        grades.ForEach(g => { g.marks = g.marks.Replace(' ', '-'); });

        string[] arr = new string[2];

        for (int i = 0; i < grades.Count; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = string.Format("[{0}, {1}, {2}]", grades[i].gradeName, grades[i].grade, grades[i].marks);

            Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
        }
```